# How to deploy vuejs - express app to local Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, express, ubuntu, vue.js, deployment

I'm wondering how to deploy vue-express full stack application to local Ubuntu server.
I couldn't find proper info from google. Can someone please explain the process?

Answer (score 0):

If you build your vue project with vue-cli 3 (which I strongly recommend), using its **npm run build** script will create a /dist folder with all the minified stuff you need.

Then, you just serve this folder with you express app, something like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('dist'))
```